# How to remove customAnimations from childFragmentManager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

The code to apply custom animations is this, though when I pass childFragmentManager to a bottom sheet dialog fragment the same animations are applied which is not even overridding.

```
.childFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            enter,
            exit,
            popEnter,
            popExit
        )
        .replace(R.id.fl_fragment_container, fragment, tag)
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .apply {
            if (shouldAddToBackStack)
                addToBackStack(tag)
        }
        .commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the animation from `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Disable dialog window animations for this instance
        dialog?.window?.setWindowAnimations(-1)
    }
```